# SublimeText3 to keep line folded

Tags: sublimetext3, editor

In SublimeText3, keyboard shortcut "Ctrl + Shift + [" is used to fold lines selected.

Even though the script file is saved. When the script file is closed, and opened again, the folded lines are automatically unfolded (like the lines had never been folded before).

Is there a way to keep the lines always folded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like the [`AutoFoldCode`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFoldCode) plugin is what you're looking for. It acts on all open files, which could be annoying. It also optionally remembers selections from session to session, which could also be useful.